# Why does a variable of blob type, when printed gives out it's size?

Tags: apex, blob, data-types

```
String str = 'myString';
Blob b = Blob.valueOf(str);
System.debug(b);
System.debug(b.size());
System.debug(str);
```

Here if I print `str` then the value of str(I believe it is using`valueOf()`method explicitly) is printed but when I print `b` then the it returns the size, why? If I want to know the value of blob(binary data for the same) then how can I extract that?

Comment: The reason why is because the Debug Logs are a UTF-8 stream, and outputting arbitrary data could make the file invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Use `EncodingUtil.base64Encode` for the contains for the Blob. Refer [EncodingUtil Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm)

```
String str = 'myString';
Blob b = Blob.valueOf(str);
System.debug(b); //it returns Blob[8]
String base64String = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b);

System.debug('encoded string=' + base64String); //it returns bXlTdHJpbmc=

System.debug('decoded string=' + EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64String).toString()); //it returns myString
```

Comment: `//it returns Blob[8]`, no it returns `8`. `System.debug(b)` returns `Blob[8]`.